# when using $localForage.setItem the App freeze for few seconds

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, localforage

I am using $localForage.setItem to store data locally in an ionic Mobile App. the data is about 7MB and the App freeze for few seconds when using setItem.

Any advice how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Promises to allow the application to keep running while the data is being fetched.

```
localforage.getItem("sellerName").then(function(sellerName) {
         // .... Any code that DEPENDS ON THIS DATA goes here.
         // THIS code will have a pause prefacing it, but code
         // outside of this funtion will continue to process.
});
```

Hope this helps you out! If your data depends on the data being retrieved, you may need to retrieve sooner (like caching it) or place a loader image on screen temporarily. Good luck!

Addendum: You could try this, I've used it for fetching "big data" and to fetch multiple big-data results...

```
var getLogs = $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: 'testget.php?more=1' });
$('#results').html('Loading...');
$.when(getLogs).then( function(getLogs) {
   $('#results').html(getLogs);
}, handleError);
function handleError(xhr, status, error) {
   console.log("There was an Error: " + error.toString());
}
```

This should handle your problem. ^5

Comment: The question is asked regarding setting item, I'am having similar issue even though using promise callback.